# how to calculate percentage in column Total in sql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql

```
RL   SumAmount      RL     SumAmount
Alex    120         Alex    24.00%  
Jonny   122         Jonny   24.40%  
Jack    13          Jack    2.60%   
David   125         David   25.00%  
Mike    120         Mike    24.00%
```

Grand Total 500     Grand Total 100.00%

I was trying to calculate percentage in column Total using sql like below screen shot but getting problem

Comment: Try something like this: `select a.RL, concat( round(100*a.n/qs.s, 2), "%") as SumAmount from a, (select sum(SumAmount) as s from a) as qs`

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: SELECT Sales_amount/500*100 from `calculator`

Comment: This kind result i expect but i have set here 500 hard coded it should calculate automatically

Comment: Table Structure

Name Sales_amount
Alex 120
Jonny 122
Jack 13
David 125
Mike 120

Answer (score 0):

To get the ratio:

```
select t.*, sumamount/tot.total
from table t cross join
     (select sum(sumamount) as total from table t) tot;
```

If you want this expressed as the percentage:

```
select t.*, concat(format(sumamount/tot.total, 2), '%')
from table t cross join
     (select sum(sumamount) as total from table t) tot;
```

Comment: tot there is problem need to calculate it how does it can be done